# Ggplot - How to fix scientific notation symbols on Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot an X discrete value and a Y continuous value.

My dataframe is as follows : Dublin_Average

**Postcode** is of type character ( CoDublin , D1 ....... )

**Price** is numeric

Here is a snippet of the data.

```
*row 1*
CoDublin
458379.8


*row 2*
D1
613516.4


*row 3*
D2
586021.3
```

I have this code for my ggplot which plots X fine but for Y it does not give me the range from lets say 100000.0 to 900000.0 .

```
ggplot(Dublin_Average, 
       aes(x = Postcode, y=Price)) +
  geom_col(fill = "blue", col = "red", alpha=I(.2), main = "Frequency of Post Code")
```

It gives me these on the Y axis instead;

```
1e+06

5e+05

0e+00
```

**I know I am missing something, how can I resolve this issue on the Y-axis ?**

Comment: You can use `library(scales)` and change the y-axis by `scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)`

Comment: In the future, please use `dput()` on your data and share it in your question. It is especially important when you want someone to help fix your plot.